# trouble printing out text from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot print out texts I made

```
if (readyToDraw) {
        json += "}";
        json += "]";
        SetTab(2);
        var html = ""; 
        if (json =="")
            json = "\"\"";
        var obj = eval("[" + json + "]"); 
        html = ProcessObject(obj[0], 0, false, false, false, false); 
        $("#requestJsonView").html('<PRE class="CodeContainer">' + html + "</PRE>");
        _jsonStringForRequest = json; 
    }
```

I'm getting error named: `VM634:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` is there any solution for this? If I try `console.log(json)` I can see my test in the console, but I cannot see in my `requestJsonView` section's text because of that error.

Comment: What this two lines `json += "}";  json += "]";` are for ?!

Comment: before the code, I have list of strings and in the view, i want to close with `}` and `]`

Comment: Then why you check this `if (json =="")` !!

Comment: oh.. but even if i dont have that, I have the same error

Comment: Certainly, the error is due to the Invalid JSON.

Comment: Go to www.jsonlint.com.  Paste your JSON in there.  Add your `}]` to the string.  Check to see if it's valid.  If it isn't, then fix it.

Comment: `["url://testtest/" {"txNo":27213924,"sessionId":"admintest"},{"appId":test1,"appSecret":d2a383eaf3d056776ef36,"playerId":id,"relationTypes":relation,}]` why is this an invalid json?

Comment: If you do as I suggested, you'll find tools to help you determine that for yourself.

Comment: thanks so much! @IsmailRBOUH

Comment: thanks so much! @BobRodes

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck!  I know fixing JSON can be frustrating.  One thing you need to do is enclose all your string values in quotes.

Comment: why don't you put the the curly brackets for your second if statement? the one inside the big if statement